# Update all npm packages without package.json handy

Tags: angularjs, npm, yeoman, updating

I've been using angular yeoman for a while now and seen that these packages get updated quite frequently:

For example these ones:

```
npm install -g generator-webapp
npm install -g generator-angular
```

When I want to update them  I just run the same commands again or run `npm update [-g] [<name> [<name> ...]]`

Is there a way to just tell npm to update them all to the latest version if I don't have a package.json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just run `npm update -g`, which will update ALL of your globally installed packages.

It also doesnt have anythign to do with the package.json, since that is for the LOCALLY defined npm-Packages (in your projects scope).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `yo` to update your generators:

[image: yo -> update your generators]

Comment: Providing information about how to update generators in a question about updating generators is possibly useful to the poster. That's why I shared this information.

Comment: Yeah it can be relevant, I didn't see the Yeoman tag on the subject, though it was all about NPM. But I can't remove my -1 until you edit your answer ... this part is a pitfall to my mind, if we do a mistake we can't undo it.